# CTE query performance improvement (postgres 9.6)

Tags: postgresql

I have got a query below that does what needed, but super slow. It returns in a given period of time (for example below between 2017-05-01 00:00:00 and 2017-05-01 01:00:00, but could be anything between 1 second and several days)  first and last records of a given intervals (15 sec as example, but could be anything from 1 second to several days).

It is unbearably slow. For example for interval on 1 second for a period 2017-05-01 00:00:00 to 2017-05-01 00:00:01 it runs 6 sec on my i7 7700HQ. for interval for 1 for period 2017-05-01 00:00:00 to 2017-05-01 00:00:05 I never saw the result! The database has about 60 millions row now. in production it will be 1 billion with approx 50 millions added every months.

QUERY:

```
WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dd as start_range, 
           dd + '15 seconds'::interval as end_range, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp 
            , '2017-05-01 01:00:00'::timestamp
            , '15 seconds'::interval) dd
), create_grp as (
    SELECT r.grp, r.start_range, r.end_range, p.*
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r
      ON p.dt >= r.start_range
      AND p.dt < r.end_range
    WHERE instrument='EURGBP'
), minmax as ( 
   SELECT row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt asc) as rn1,
          row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt desc) as rn2,              
          create_grp.*
   FROM create_grp 
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1 THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'first'
            WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM minmax
WHERE 
    1 IN (rn1, rn2) 
ORDER BY dt
;
```

SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE public.prices
(
    uid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    instrument character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    bid double precision NOT NULL,
    ask double precision NOT NULL,
    dt timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

INDEXES:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_dt_instrument
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (dt, instrument COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_dt_instrument_bid_ask
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (dt, instrument COLLATE pg_catalog."default", bid, ask)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_instrument
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (instrument COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

EXAMPLE dataset for 5 seconds staring from 2017-05-01 00:00:00:

```
"uid","instrument","bid","ask","dt"
"4ecaa607-3733-4aba-9093-abc8f59e1638","EURGBP","0.84331","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:00:00.031"
"d1a41847-4945-4cf4-a45f-781db977ae07","GBPJPY","143.949005","143.970993","2017-05-01 00:00:00.031"
"34972c12-899b-404a-b0de-bae0fd3f6733","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.970993","2017-05-01 00:00:00.056"
"384b8246-3eac-4826-b6d2-d6caaa364f81","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29323","2017-05-01 00:00:00.066"
"d879b04d-a4ed-452e-9208-7dfff672e860","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.970993","2017-05-01 00:00:00.067"
"a9e735ec-30d9-4c9a-a28e-5e5553273372","GBPJPY","143.945999","143.970993","2017-05-01 00:00:00.079"
"ee40ee5f-d8ac-41ce-9f39-ae50ef15d02d","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964005","2017-05-01 00:00:00.091"
"7b605c3b-121f-46c2-a3e4-297d187f0a28","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.115"
"ccb307b0-7fa3-4354-8707-1426eded49e8","GBPJPY","143.942001","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.205"
"206c339d-bc36-469d-82d1-c7ae74002f44","EURGBP","0.84332","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:00:00.206"
"bc581318-91c7-4c80-85e0-e06f7236b277","GBPJPY","143.944","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.206"
"1fabf850-9045-4beb-81ae-bfa3adada62e","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29324","2017-05-01 00:00:00.208"
"06d40f9a-a47e-466d-aebf-97a0154bdc74","GBPJPY","143.942001","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.209"
"b3b7fac9-340f-4e3b-8946-7bdecc383191","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:00.211"
"b5c28955-b40f-446f-9f43-9d5e9f145c1b","EURGBP","0.84331","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:00:00.212"
"192a40d6-8001-42ea-9430-96e800f2d4e8","GBPJPY","143.942993","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.212"
"e98dbba7-8231-4fa3-926b-291eb22b0f87","GBPJPY","143.944","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.215"
"7c6e952d-d01f-4dac-a1df-6b32168246fd","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:00.216"
"c86ba29f-3edb-4147-ba99-d9dfe594b0ff","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:00.243"
"35ca131e-b714-462d-827f-b5bc593aa3e6","GBPJPY","143.942993","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.262"
"91fc6fc0-7af9-4036-8e0e-29d4a3bb3e43","EURGBP","0.8433","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:00:00.283"
"e71946e0-1859-461a-b3eb-0539584ac4dc","GBPJPY","143.944","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.296"
"7321eea8-2610-408b-8dbf-4087f01e8c6e","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.377"
"f146716d-cadf-4e2f-9f17-6e7e8c5f2175","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:00.38"
"b3d81295-8cd5-44e7-879c-f15476ffac21","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:00.391"
"c037e27b-a8f4-4ec3-8472-b0f72a58fd33","EURGBP","0.8433","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:00:00.413"
"dba0f8f5-f218-49ea-8ebf-132f3ecf8910","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.443"
"a08449e3-44aa-4fed-b8e9-bf1a6bfc35c5","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:00.585"
"a0b7ba20-653f-46db-93e9-d1edd8972dba","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:00.588"
"c2855ce8-8c5b-4de7-a92b-186d928e8f31","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.591"
"01b19a70-3ce7-44c7-9abd-9945321fdfd0","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:00.621"
"4518aa9d-1f76-428e-ace4-7dcffeb6aa22","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.796"
"e4d4bac4-dd02-4da3-b231-20bfa6424412","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:00.907"
"e48d3721-3157-4033-bd4f-09baae0f989c","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:00.909"
"64a33b2d-c756-4a0a-823e-075143ae7263","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.913"
"e477c47d-efd1-44dd-8058-cac17e08bc5d","GBPUSD","1.29314","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:00.914"
"cf6d5341-f7fd-47bc-89f6-a5448f78fb99","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:00.943"
"4caa8bb9-094e-48ca-8a9a-7b2dd23a4fb4","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:00.967"
"274b7f51-3b07-430d-bfc5-a0b1ce62a750","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:00.975"
"2e3c2cd6-2525-46b3-86c5-b88e48bb0138","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.076"
"bcb12b90-2795-4789-bfa2-8e9a494eaeb1","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:01.076"
"d63d6037-fa81-47cc-bd62-4655850c0f80","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:01.077"
"6dbf8d8e-37c8-4537-80b5-c9219f4356b1","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:01.079"
"7e3b6eaf-22e1-4f87-a7c1-226d3ee76146","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:01.08"
"63e451c5-b8c6-4b57-ac9e-2171bc1dfbfa","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.121"
"866316e7-90a2-4c80-9a38-b3a062837415","GBPJPY","143.949005","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.143"
"fb11e963-cd36-4cfc-89b3-1bba3b8595b5","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:01.156"
"ad57e34f-5cbe-4b79-8579-b2c77c83b50b","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:01.249"
"46b1840e-e424-41c2-8c71-691b201183ab","GBPJPY","143.949005","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.259"
"c5fa5e09-46df-4ea4-8640-9cf18e1f8fcc","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:01.265"
"926d092d-601e-43ec-b398-3300b0345cfd","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.267"
"4ddfbc84-20a1-4281-86c2-f0a4e77d0152","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:01.305"
"e75af139-51a2-4a0a-acc8-e0adfbe5472a","GBPUSD","1.29313","1.29327","2017-05-01 00:00:01.346"
"408bca2d-2d57-471b-b6a7-819a3257741f","GBPJPY","143.951004","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.348"
"53c6f444-bd76-4a28-a370-7af98d5fa9ec","GBPUSD","1.29313","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:01.359"
"cd002ef4-925e-469b-8f2f-848cadd5943f","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:01.443"
"13587e44-b694-4ce9-a626-e592d28c507d","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:01.45"
"aabbacaf-3f09-4313-b992-e8b8d91df7ad","GBPJPY","143.951004","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.461"
"6b2111ef-c285-4482-b93c-238f27522ca3","GBPUSD","1.29313","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:01.477"
"19507f29-149c-4fdf-a1fa-aac312ab8479","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:00:01.506"
"916cc759-a536-449d-b825-8203ebea9bf8","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.649"
"1fdd2b35-fd44-4dbb-81df-b98514af7004","GBPUSD","1.29313","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:01.649"
"3e9fc214-3cc6-4991-9eb3-2f5a5e557e96","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29326","2017-05-01 00:00:01.65"
"5da9a29b-0d8a-42b1-98b6-f89dd2893c77","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:00:01.651"
"b87f85e3-fba5-4556-8ca5-52625d978d53","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:00:01.652"
"75b7624c-b90c-40d4-a7fc-09df7da9f659","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.715"
"b076534f-b893-4b55-9d9a-e3bac6e77ab2","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:01.732"
"6464da85-9eb5-4548-bd5e-3331a69f2121","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:00:01.817"
"f9937464-e36a-4c57-a212-2f32943307d3","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:00:01.83"
"1c7848e5-c101-4a50-87fe-1f5e980dbb95","GBPJPY","143.949005","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:01.83"
"30ad5bfc-f968-4b49-9b22-80c12e801f37","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:01.847"
"94eb4b51-4901-4e56-873a-05f93ef35e64","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:00:02.007"
"97ef7e05-0a2f-4d70-80d1-1d3c748ea70f","GBPJPY","143.949005","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:02.007"
"af9274d9-02d6-43fc-9336-c3f512e4bd78","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:02.008"
"78c12ba8-992a-469e-bdda-bef004596aa1","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:02.062"
"4e1e31a9-bfdc-4f56-b8e1-0c7e83852fe0","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29324","2017-05-01 00:00:02.071"
"e4f1c459-f75b-4005-8dd1-00c572ded4f9","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29324","2017-05-01 00:00:02.203"
"2c8b38ce-50de-43e7-ba63-b6d1d7a7f76c","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:02.244"
"438f4439-a259-421f-8f45-a0dc88d80e1d","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:02.257"
"f12b7e18-84f0-4686-9588-0ecfab8f8bf8","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29324","2017-05-01 00:00:02.301"
"f335ee32-cd5e-4cd2-aabe-06c14985778f","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:02.394"
"3c55786e-f9b8-424b-9c32-0b4b432a553f","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:00:02.404"
"53c3e013-b016-41bb-a3ed-48158640831a","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29324","2017-05-01 00:00:02.417"
"a944e2b6-3700-4ecd-994d-cb5ab97cf5ad","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:02.508"
"ab32781d-1502-4047-b320-c3f4cda389fd","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:02.605"
"24759950-e095-4bb7-be3d-fda725423589","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:02.625"
"cd7940d9-8a30-4a12-9dc9-a2c710cbb982","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:02.649"
"233e0a3d-eeae-403f-b512-2add055d6735","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:02.761"
"58c7c33c-75b2-45bd-a50c-615d9eaaec07","EURGBP","0.84329","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:02.763"
"675b2847-b0f9-44f1-ab75-d6ddafbddfd5","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:02.766"
"d2946714-e84c-4a36-9819-0cca4f2dd197","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:02.81"
"5322418b-4c45-4771-b591-cc8fea167424","GBPJPY","143.949997","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:02.832"
"9a1c572e-28b9-4d16-b196-ccef3e48f602","EURGBP","0.84331","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:02.929"
"a4377169-5400-4dd6-81f0-8b455d178b65","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:02.951"
"37cdddb0-db5e-4574-bf4d-45fb8d52c6be","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:02.951"
"1258c886-b797-43ed-9886-323daac83dde","GBPUSD","1.29311","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:02.999"
"453406c3-5902-4dab-b39c-2e0b85739767","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:03.005"
"95699a6d-8412-4f2f-9dd4-86a1d3eed57d","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:03.129"
"2268fcc4-104e-434b-8237-bce765bda084","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:03.131"
"ba771b59-b04c-4683-8ceb-8e9b8451bcc7","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:03.17"
"00541afa-79a6-4d09-8c6e-4d59e8d15bb2","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.968994","2017-05-01 00:00:03.216"
"b4dd6e15-0e25-4da1-b210-021b91e4245a","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:03.323"
"79b11513-97c5-4146-a4c8-7daf7d8ffe6f","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.966995","2017-05-01 00:00:03.324"
"c5283502-eb09-45d3-b92b-d5625de9e9fc","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.966003","2017-05-01 00:00:03.411"
"67715855-9171-4ae7-b205-5ba017d328f2","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:03.501"
"00b7647e-7d53-407d-9704-78a8712ac580","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.966003","2017-05-01 00:00:03.525"
"b41b5483-5fb2-4c57-9892-0d02e5e6a823","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.966003","2017-05-01 00:00:03.549"
"881712b2-ff9a-4065-ad6a-9caee03283e3","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.964996","2017-05-01 00:00:03.56"
"7248bc13-5a9f-4fba-97a1-fe041e975c38","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:03.581"
"0379b4bb-7691-48e8-a668-2388f6e5d510","GBPJPY","143.947998","143.964996","2017-05-01 00:00:03.672"
"2715fe9a-eb6f-445d-b7d0-850293bb5b2e","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964996","2017-05-01 00:00:03.698"
"52ce7685-0964-46e4-ab8f-282e68bdb73d","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964005","2017-05-01 00:00:03.711"
"6b31dee4-1aec-4d10-9b37-0c58bae7e449","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964005","2017-05-01 00:00:03.848"
"7e61571a-ea8b-44cb-9481-ae31ba8b86c4","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:03.868"
"89e316cb-e01d-4f01-9dcd-a380e94ed4e8","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964005","2017-05-01 00:00:03.943"
"966318e4-a6b5-4c1b-82e1-fbbf0029ce02","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:04.096"
"8fc7b075-7f5e-40f5-9879-55604f77a3c5","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:04.227"
"23ab8b66-337e-4c4e-b73a-f31101716565","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964005","2017-05-01 00:00:04.227"
"eb7469be-8a40-4498-af85-7b2c42630149","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964005","2017-05-01 00:00:04.288"
"f945a821-9790-4760-beea-1b54bb1c2a85","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:04.406"
"978c6d4c-22f9-4218-b447-940a3d3c436e","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:04.505"
"2ace7d77-b228-491c-9cf0-610b8e48cdf7","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.966003","2017-05-01 00:00:04.786"
"0f89d5dd-52f2-44e9-aa54-cbb423cd7416","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.964996","2017-05-01 00:00:04.787"
"db7748a8-317b-4c62-a1f2-d6679430b343","GBPUSD","1.29312","1.29325","2017-05-01 00:00:04.895"
"ae29728e-773b-42a9-9f1e-199ba996731a","EURGBP","0.8433","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:00:04.986"
"19ffa8e4-63c5-4f47-90d5-771dd5a839ba","GBPJPY","143.947006","143.962997","2017-05-01 00:00:04.986"
```

The slowdown is caused by " WHERE instrument='EURGBP' ". As soon as I remove it the query flies. However, I must have filtering by 'instrument'.

EXPLAIN OUTPUT:

```
Sort  (cost=2356660289.95..2356711257.16 rows=20386886 width=144)
  Sort Key: minmax.dt
  CTE ranges
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..25.00 rows=1000 width=24)
          ->  Function Scan on generate_series dd  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8)
  CTE create_grp
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=344299.48..460976348.77 rows=2043798111 width=71)
          Join Filter: ((p.dt >= r.start_range) AND (p.dt < r.end_range))
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on prices p  (cost=344299.48..1121763.77 rows=18394183 width=47)
                Recheck Cond: ((instrument)::text = 'EURGBP'::text)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_instrument  (cost=0.00..339700.94 rows=18394183 width=0)
                      Index Cond: ((instrument)::text = 'EURGBP'::text)
          ->  CTE Scan on ranges r  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=24)
  CTE minmax
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1796644092.85..1837520055.07 rows=2043798111 width=112)
          ->  Sort  (cost=1796644092.85..1801753588.13 rows=2043798111 width=104)
                Sort Key: create_grp.grp, create_grp.dt DESC
                ->  WindowAgg  (cost=880857947.67..921733909.89 rows=2043798111 width=104)
                      ->  Sort  (cost=880857947.67..885967442.95 rows=2043798111 width=96)
                            Sort Key: create_grp.grp, create_grp.dt
                            ->  CTE Scan on create_grp  (cost=0.00..40875962.22 rows=2043798111 width=96)
  ->  CTE Scan on minmax  (cost=0.00..51298821.64 rows=20386886 width=144)
        Filter: ((1 = rn1) OR (1 = rn2))
```

Any suggestions to optimize it are very very welcome.

Comment: Does `EXPLAIN` show that the index on the `WHERE` clause is being used?

Comment: You were already told in reactions to your original question : the query is slow *because* of the CTE and the generate_series(), which both lack indexes to join on, and/or usable statistics. IOW: materialize them. (The `WHERE instrument='EURGBP'` condition is the **strongest** hint, causing the planner to flip its mind)

Comment: I'm new to the whole SQL thing. Can I use Temp Table in here somehow? What does 'materialize' mean? How do I materialize them?

Comment: BTW:your indexes make no sense(one is a subset of the other) And adding the attributes(bid,ask) to  the index is relatively useless anyway, the other two components are *allmost* a candidate key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE ranges
        ( start_range timestamp NOT NULL
        , end_range timestamp NOT NULL
        , grp INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
        , PRIMARY KEY (start_range)
        );
INSERT INTO ranges(start_range, end_range, grp)
SELECT dd as start_range,
           dd + '1 seconds'::interval as end_range,
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp
            , '2017-05-01 01:00:00'::timestamp
            --, '15 seconds'::interval) dd
            , '1 seconds'::interval) dd
        ;

VACUUM ANALYZE ranges;

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1 THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'first'
            WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM (
    SELECT r.grp, p.uid, p.instrument, r.start_range , p.dt AS dt
           , p.bid, p.ask
        , row_number() over (partition by r.grp order by p.dt asc) as rn1
        , row_number() over (partition by r.grp order by p.dt desc) as rn2
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r ON p.dt >= r.start_range AND p.dt < r.end_range
    WHERE p.instrument='EURGBP'
        ) zzzz
WHERE (rn1=1 OR rn2=1)
-- ORDER BY instrument,grp, dt
        ;
```

---

And, you don't actually need the row number, since you only want the beginning/end of a window:

---

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN (prev IS NULL AND next IS NULL) THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN prev IS NULL THEN 'first'
            WHEN next IS NULL THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM (
    SELECT r.grp, p.uid, p.instrument, r.start_range , p.dt AS dt, p.bid, p.ask
        , lag(uid) over (www) as prev
        , lead(uid) over (www) as next
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r ON p.dt >= r.start_range AND p.dt < r.end_range
    WHERE p.instrument='EURGBP'
        WINDOW www AS (partition by r.grp order by p.dt )
        -- ORDER BY p.instrument,r.grp, p.dt
        ) qqqq
WHERE (prev IS NULL OR next IS NULL)
-- ORDER BY instrument,grp, dt
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks for refactoring. However, your approach is even slower the original. I'm not sure why. Original query for the same period (1 sec) and same interval (1sec) runs in 10 sec. Yours in 12. I guess the database size of 60mills matters.

Comment: Tuning matters. Cardinality matters. Indexes matter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for help and hints! Apparently if I move WHERE clause from create_gpr to minimax, the query become extremely fast. I have no explanation to it whatsoever. But it works. Here it is:

```
WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dd as start_range, 
           dd + '1 seconds'::interval as end_range, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp 
            , '2017-05-01 00:01:00'::timestamp
            , '1 seconds'::interval) dd
), create_grp as (
    SELECT r.grp, r.start_range, r.end_range, p.*
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r
      ON p.dt >= r.start_range
     AND p.dt < r.end_range
-- WHERE need to be moved out of here, which has no indexes as being temporary
--  WHERE instrument='EURGBP'
), minmax as ( 
   SELECT row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt asc) as rn1,
          row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt desc) as rn2,              
          create_grp.*
   FROM create_grp
-- Here WHERE goes! It does use index here for some reason. And the query flies.
   WHERE instrument='EURGBP'
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1 THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'first'
            WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM minmax
WHERE 
    1 IN (rn1, rn2) 
ORDER BY dt
;
```

This query (for 1 minute range) runs in 84 msec, the old one never finished to run (I gave up after 10 minutes). The old query took 10 sec to run for the range of 1 sec.

Thanks to everyone for help!